# Is my PC fault, or android emulator is slow

Tags: android, performance, simulator

I'm on the learning stage of android and I have to run/debug my application in emulator very often. The thing is that between I press the debug button and until the application gets started on the emulator I have to wait 1-2 minutes.

Is this normal? My PC is a i5 with 8GB RAM.

Comment: That has been my experience.  I'm not sure if it's normal, but I've definitely had enough speed problems that I slowed down any android work.

Comment: Which version of Android are you emulating? In my experience the emulator for Android 4.0 is really, really resource demanding. I switched to Android 2.2 and it takes a lot less time. Also, you should reduce the emulated SD card memory to speed up things.

Comment: Btw, I also believe that the emulator is better integrated into the Linux kernel,so switching from Win to Linux/iOS might improve performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emulator is certainly not fast, but one thing you should do is to make sure you don't close the emulator. Leave it running, and then most of the initial startup time will be taken care of. The emulator is a real emulator (unlike the iOS simulator). Think of the startup time of the emulator as booting up your phone. You're not going to turn off and turn on your phone every time you want to use an app, so similarly with the emulator, just leave it on.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not normal, but it’s as expected. The Android emulator continues to be very slow and basically unusable for development. You’re better off developing on a real device. (Deployment to real device is much faster with Android IDE than it is on Xcode/iOS.)

Google has stated that it is a known issue, but it’s not known if/when it actually will get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced startup times of 5-10 minutes for the emulator to start up.  The startup time to start debugging your application is going to depend on the size of your application.  It has to tranfser the .apk over each time you want to debug.  If your application is full of large files this can be a long time.  One time I put a video in my res/raw folder and it brought my application to 25 mb.  This ended up taking around 5 minutes to start debugging.